# serialport for electron NODE_MODULE_VERSION error and rebuild does not fix

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-rebuild

OS: win 10
Node.js : v12.18.3
electron: v10.1.1

print version from js program:
process.versions.node 12.16.3
process.versions.modules 82

1. install serialport by:
   npm install serialport
2. npm start and get error:

Error: The module '\?\D:\node\Tester\node_modules@serialport\bindings\build\Release\bindings.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 82. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).

3. npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild
   .\node_modules.bin\electron-rebuild

Rebuild Complete

4. npm start
   and the error again.

Error: The module '\?\D:\node\Tester\node_modules@serialport\bindings\build\Release\bindings.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 82. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).

What should be noticed is, both v12.18.3 and 12.16.3 has NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. and no version gets 82.
I don't know where the '82' comes from.
How can I sovle it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue this morning. With over 5 hours of troubleshooting the only thing that worked for me was to downgrade electron-rebuild to v2.0.1. I am using node v14.9.0(latest), electron v10.1.1(latest), serialport v9.0.1(latest)

Looks like they have an issue open: https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild/issues/404

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem. Finally, i can solve this with some steps. Here they are.

### 1. install electron-rebuild

```
npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild
```

### 2. Run some script

#### On MacOS, run this

```
./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild
```

#### On Windows, try:

```
.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd
```

### 3. Add start script in package.json

```
"rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w serialport"
```

### 4. Rebuild the project

```
npm run rebuild
```

I hope it will help you. have a nice day.