# Why is there a mismatch of module versions between Electron and Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, electron

I have a node project in which I use NodeJS `14.15.0` and the latest build of Electron `12.0.0`.

NodeJS version `14.15.0` has a `NODE_MODULE_VERSION` **83** according to their [webpage](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/).

[image]

Electron version `v12.0.0` uses this node version of `14.15.0`. but on their [webpage](https://github.com/electron/releases) it says the module `NODE_MODULE_VERSION` is **87**

[image]

Therefore I have a mismatch between these two versions. I need a match so I can load the same binary intro an Electron app + execute by a node.js instance.

Comment: ``To bounty hunters``: This question is different to a previous of mine I asked a few weeks ago, but anyone who can solve this question potentially solves my other question which has an active bounty of `+100!` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625765/incorrect-node-module-version-when-using-ava

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Electron maintains and compiles their own fork of Node, in a way that may not be compatible with normal Node. Electron intentionally uses unique `NODE_MODULE_VERSION` to signal this fact to software.

You'll need to recompile native modules using `electron-rebuild`.

> Native Node modules are supported by Electron, but since Electron is very likely to use a different V8 version from the Node binary installed on your system, the modules you use will need to be recompiled for Electron.

([electron docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules))

The maintainers of Node and Electron discussed possible options, and decided to use offset versioning in this issue:

https://github.com/nodejs/TSC/issues/651

Comment: Thank you sooo much! This makes so much sense now! Please feel free to take this answer and copy it to my other question or just post a link to get the 100 points bounty. I was looking for this information everywhere and simply missed this.